# How to add default date to page title of my custom template?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

I have created a template called "TODO with Date". It was created based on a page so every time I create a page using this template it creates the page with "TODO: 2014-03-04" title. Well its easy to change title every day I create it but I was wondering if there is a way to add date (any format) in the page title?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation and verified by experience, the correct key sequence to insert the current date is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  Additional shortcuts can be found at "[139 Keyboard Shortcuts for OneNote 2010](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/OneNote_2010.html)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use two shortcuts in this case: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for current date or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for current date with time.

Comment: it didnt work in onenote 2013 version.

Comment: I use onenote 2013 and it works like a charm.